# Using XLOCK In SELECT Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is using XLOCK (Exclusive Lock) in SELECT statements considered bad practice?

Let's assume the simple scenario where a customer's account balance is $40. Two concurrent $20 puchase requests arrive. Transaction includes:

1. Read balance
2. If customer has enough money, deduct the price of the product from the balance

So without XLOCK:

1. T1(Transaction1) reads $40.
2. T2 reads $40.
3. T1 updates it to $20.
4. T2 updates it to $20.

But there should be $0 left in the account.

Is there a way to prevent this without the use of XLOCK? What are the alternatives?

Comment: There is ample literature available on the topic, comparing optimistic concurrency vs. pessimistic concurrency, and specifics how to implement them. Go read some. Hints are bad, XLOCK hints are particularly bad.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an update, you should update directly into the data item to prevent these issues. One safe way to do this is demonstrated in the sample code below:

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomerBalance (CustID int not null, Balance decimal(9,2) not null)
INSERT INTO #CustomerBalance Values (1, 40.00)

DECLARE @TransactionAmount decimal(9,2) = 19.00
DECLARE @RemainingBalance decimal(9,2)

UPDATE #CustomerBalance
SET @RemainingBalance = Balance - @TransactionAmount,
    Balance = @RemainingBalance

SELECT @RemainingBalance

(No column name)
21.00
```

One advantage of this method is that the row is locked as soon as the `UPDATE` statement starts executing. If two users are updating the value "simultaneously", because of how the database works, one will start updating the data before the other. The first `UPDATE` will prevent the second `UPDATE` from manipulating the data until the first one is completed. When the second `UPDATE` starts processing the record, it will see the value that has been updated into the Balance by the first update.

As a side effect of this, you will want to have code that checks the balance after your update, and roll back the value if you have "overdrawn" the balance, or whatever is necessary. That is why this sample code returns the remaining balance in the variable @RemainingBalance.

Comment: What would be your opinion on the scalability of this approach if the scenario required more complex checks such as joins etc.?

Comment: And on queries operating on a range of rows?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you place the queries, isolation level `READ COMMITTED` should do the job.
Suppose the following code to be performed:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
start transaction;
update account set balance=balance-20 where accountid = 'XY';
commit;
```

Assume T1 executes statement `update account set balance=balance-20 where accountid = 'XY'`; it will place a write lock on the record with accountid='XY'.
If now a second transaction T2 executes the same statement before T1 has committed, than the statement of T2 is blocked until T1 commits.
Afterwards, T2 continues. At the end, balance will be reduced by `40`.

Comment: What would be your opinion on the scalability of this approach if the scenario required more complex checks such as joins etc.?

Comment: And on queries operating on a range of rows?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is based on the assumption that using `XLOCK` is a bad practice. While it is correct that putting this hint everywhere all the time is generally not the best possible approach, there is no other way to achieve the required functionality in your particular situation.

When I encountered the same problem, I have found that the combination of `XLOCK, HOLDLOCK` placed in the verification `select` in the same transaction usually gets the job done. (I had a stored procedure that performs all necessary validations and then updated the Accounts table only if everything is fine. Yes, in a single transaction.)

However, there is one important caveat: if your database has RCSI enabled, other readers will be able to get past the lock by getting previous value from the version store. In this case, adding `READCOMMITTEDLOCK` turns off optimistic versioning for the row(s) in question and reverts the behaviour back to standard RC.